# how to display real-time visitor counts on my wordpress website(count changes)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've made website with wordpress and connected with Google Analytics right now.

I want to show the count of current online visitor, just the number.
But it's hard for me to find the solution.

I've used the other plugins but they shows not only the number.
[not like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUduw.png)
and i want this number changes automatically, not with the refresh.

I need
1. the number of real-time visitors of my site
2. and this number changes automatically as online visitors change

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin.

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/

If you want not to display a certain element of it just try to find the css class or ID and hide it with:

> display: none!important;

It would be helpful to see your site to help you more in detail.